# Can't get Sails Socket to work

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

It's been a few days figuring out sails socket works but I've no luck to get it working on my sails project.

So i have a model called Events.

In client Side Javascript

```
  var socket = io.socket;
  socket.on('connect',function socketConnected(){
    console.log("connected");
    socket.get('/events/getData',function getEvents(events){
      addEvents(events);
    });
    socket.on('events',function eventFound(eventData){
      console.log('something happend');
      addEvents(eventData);
    });
  });
```

And on ServerSide events controller .

```
'create': function(req,res){
    var eventsData = u.getParams(req);
    Events.create(eventsData,function created(err,createdEvent){
      Events.publishCreate(createdEvent);
      console.log("created");
      return res.send(200);
    });
  },
  'getData': function(req, res) {
    Events.find().exec(function foundEvent(err, event) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      Events.subscribe(req.socket, event);

      res.send(event);
    });
```

So what i expected is , when i POST an event Object to http://localhost:1337/events/create the

```
"socket.on('events',function eventFound(eventData){"
```

should've trigger right? I just cannot get it to trigger  :( is there anything I've done wrong on this? Because I'm sure that I misunderstand this socket concept somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I've got what I wanted which is adding

```
Events.watch(req)
```

in getData function, and adding

```
sails.sockets.blast(createdEvent);
```

right after

```
Events.publishCreate(createdEvent);
```

in create function.

Answer (score 0):

`.subscribe()` subscribes to updates / deletions of certain model *instances*. So if any changes are made to those specific model instances, the connected sockets will be notified. If you want to watch for *new* model instances, you should use `.watch()` instead. So instead of

```
Events.subscribe(req.socket, event);
```

you should write

```
Events.watch(req.socket);
```

Also, the syntax depends on the Sails.js version, as in v0.12 there were some changes to the sockets. If you're using v0.12 or later (you can check from the command line with `sails -v`), the correct syntax would be

```
Events.watch(req);
```

Here are the links to the relevant docs:

`.subscribe()`: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/subscribe

`.watch()`: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/watch

Comment: yes i did tried with .watch() still the same but eventually on the create controller I've added sails.sockets.blast(createdEvent); and this one works as I needed it to be :D thanks anyway for your kind reply and explanation